# Error trying to "catkin_make" ar_pose package

Tags: catkin-make, ar-pose, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I need to read some tags using the kinect. However, even after I installed the dependencies and built the package (commands `rosdep install ar_pose -i` and `rosmake ar_pose`), when I try to launch the test:

```
roslaunch ar_pose ar_pose_single.launch
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ar_pose/ar_single]: can't locate node [ar_single] in package [ar_pose]
```

I cloned the package from [ar_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_tools) and built in my catkin workspace.
Can anyone help me? I'm working with ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

***EDIT1:***

Dan, thanks again for your help. I already tried that with no success, I still get the same error when I try to catkin_make. I even erased my build and devel folders to build up my workspace again.

***EDIT2:***

Dan,

Thanks for your answer. However, I'm still experiencing a problem. When I try to `catkin_make install` I receive the following error:

Do you know what could be the problem?

```
Linking CXX executable /home/leandrosavieira/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_multi
Linking CXX executable /home/leandrosavieira/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_single
CMakeFiles/ar_single.dir/src/ar_single.cpp.o: na função `ar_pose::ARSinglePublisher::getTransformationCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
ar_single.cpp:(.text+0x318d): referência indefinida para `_IplImage::_IplImage(cv::Mat const&)'
CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.cpp.o: na função `ar_pose::ARMultiPublisher::getTransformationCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
ar_multi.cpp:(.text+0x2569): referência indefinida para `_IplImage::_IplImage(cv::Mat const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: ** [/home/leandrosavieira/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_single] Erro 1make[2]: 
** [/home/leandrosavieira/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_multi] Erro 1
make[1]: ** [ar_tools/ar_pose/CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/all] Erro 2
make[1]: ** Esperando que outros processos terminem.
make[1]: ** [ar_tools/ar_pose/CMakeFiles/ar_single.dir/all] Erro 2
make: ** [all] Erro 2
Invoking "make install -j4 -l4" failed
```

***EDIT 3:***

I tryed what Dan said but I already had `libopencv-dev` installed in my computer. Therefore, I'm still with the same problem. However, I never used Opencv before so I don't really know if I have to have anything else installed. Do I need to install it from [here](http://opencv.org/downloads.html).

***EDIT 4:***

I think I got it right now after building [vision_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv) in the catkin_workspace. Opencv was missing in my computer even though I had it in the `share` folder. It now compiles with no errors. Thanks for all the help Dan and Procópio.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209293/error-trying-to-%22catkin_make%22-ar_pose-package/) by [Leandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/22435/leandro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ar_tools do work under indigo. checking your error it seems you don't have opencv installed. is that the case?

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-05-22**:
Indeed. I would have expected some of the other upstream dependencies to pull in opencv, but maybe not. @Leandro, can you try adding `<build_depend>libopencv-dev</build_depend>` to ar_pose's package.xml, rerun `rosdep install` and try `catkin_make` again?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ar_tools is a catkin package, and should be built using the [catkin instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace). I will update the wiki page to reflect that.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-05-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1